# Hadoop can't execute a basic Example

Tags: hadoop

The software I'm using:

- System:macOS Mojave 10.14.2
- Hadoop:3.1.1
- JDK:10.0.2

I execute this command:`hadoop jar /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/libexec/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.1.1.jar pi 2 5`, it failed:

[image: error feedback]

**I need help, thank you!!!**

In hadoop-env.sh, I just add the sentence:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
```

core-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
```

hdfs-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
</property>
```

mapred-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.application.classpath</name>
    <value>$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*</value>
</property>
```

yarn-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.env-whitelist</name>
    <value>JAVA_HOME,HADOOP_COMMON_HOME,HADOOP_HDFS_HOME,HADOOP_CONF_DIR,CLASSPATH_PREPEND_DISTCACHE,HADOOP_YARN_HOME,HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.
It's the reason of java version.
When I added the two lines of code to yarn-env.sh, it didnt't work for me.

```
export YARN_RESOURCEMANAGER_OPTS="--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM"
export YARN_NODEMANAGER_OPTS="--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM"
```

In the end, I change the java version, set it to java8 and deleted above two lines of code, it worked for me.
You can set it in hadoop-env.sh.
Thx